# IPTABLES to block all outgoing connections except selected networks

Tags: iptables

There is a firewall/gateway machine with eth0 Public and eth1 Private network (`192.168.1.0`).

I would like to block all OUTPUT connections for private users (eth1)
except couple of networks like: `123.123.123.0/24`, `91.12.31.0/24` etc. as they are in our city network.

There are a lot of questions here about iptables but I couldn't find a way to resolve this issue.

It might also happen that some user, say, 192.168.1.10 would not be restricted to those networks.

If I do:

```
IPTABLES -P OUTPUT DROP
IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -d 123.123.123.0/24 -s 192.168.1.51 -j ACCEPT
...that would make me adding rules per user multiplied by number of networks
```

So is there any way to GROUP those city networks as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me that what you want is ipsets. [Here](http://www.itech7.com/Firewall/Blocking-IPs-by-country-using-IPSet-and-IPTables.html) is link that human beings can read. For installation, if you are on Fedora take a look at [this](http://supportex.net/2011/02/block-huge-amount-ip-addresses-ipset-fedora-14/)
And if on Ubuntu look at [this](http://pepoluan.posterous.com/powertip-howto-install-ipset-on-ubuntu).